When new entry (new row) under column A, then copy template worksheet and link cell and name sheet against new entry name
can anyone help me with this, pls?
I'm looking for a solution which would follow those steps below:
1 - Every time a new entry (new row) under column A (let's say "Client Name") in the tab called Summary, then copy template worksheet (called Template) and link cell and name sheet against new entry name
2 - VBA automation would check if any tab created previously has the same name, if it has then it should pops up a message "Template with same "Client ABC" was created previously.
I have tried this VBA below, but this one doesn't work when column A ("Client Name") has new entries... this VBA only works once. Like having a blank table, then filling up with customer names, then running it once to copy the template against each customer name and linking it.
Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
 End Function

Sub CreateSummarySheets(SummaryWS As Worksheet, TemplateWS As Worksheet)

    Dim newWS As Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim answer  As Long

    lastRow = SummaryWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rCell In SummaryWS.Range("$A$2:$A$" & lastRow)
      'Add copy of template
        TemplateWS.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Set newWS = Sheets(Sheets.Count)

      'Sheet exists error checking
        answer = 1
        If SheetExists(newWS.Name) = False Then
            answer = vbNo
            answer = MsgBox("Sheet with the name " & rCell.Value & " already exists.  Delete it?", vbYesNo, rCell.Value & " Sheet Exists")
        End If

        If answer = vbYes Then
            Sheets(rCell.Value).Delete
        End If
        If answer = 1 Or answer = vbYes Then
            newWS.Name = rCell.Value
        End If

      'Populate newWS's cell A1
        newWS.Cells(1, "A") = rCell.Value
      'Add Hyperlink from summary to newWS
        newWS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rCell, Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & newWS.Name & "'" & "!A2", TextToDisplay:=newWS.Name
    Next rCell

End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim s_ws As Worksheet
    Set s_ws = Sheets("Summary")

  'Two ways to run this function
    Call CreateSummarySheets(s_ws, Sheets("Template"))
End Sub


Remove the On Error Resume Next so that you can see any error and go from there.

Hi @MT1, thanks for your comment.
Can you help me with the code for I get through it, pls?
I don't get it how to complete successfully the step 2 as shown below.
Step 1 works fine (see above).
Step 2: VBA automation would check if any tab created previously has the same name, if it has then it should pops up a message "Template with same "Client ABC" was created previously.
Tab called "Summary" will have new clients being added at any time and day. The VBA I shared above only works once...
Many thanks for your help.

'If SheetExists(newWS.Name) = False Then' should say = True I would think...

The SheetExists function does not work. The line Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName) fails when the new sheet does not exist. Remove the On Error Resume Next and go from there.

Welcome Guilherme! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

The SheetExists function should return either True or False explicitly

Put Option Explicit before your subroutine or function and declare (Dim) all variables.

Fully test the SheetExists function in isolation, what happens when the string provided as a new sheet name is invalid as far as Excel is concerned?

Hi MT1, many thanks for all your orientation above. It worked form me!
Brilliant!
